# Can I view a cancelled event on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I've cancelled a Facebook event on a page I administer -- I was expecting the event to remain in the events page, but marked Cancelled, but it appears to have been completely removed.   Is there some option similar to "View Past Events" for cancelled events?

Answer (score 1):

if you can find the numeric ID of the event, (maybe its in a previous email notification you have recieved about the event) you could look up the events details via the Facebook API

the event ID is the number in the URL after "/events/"
for example in the following event URL
https://www.facebook.com/events/123456789/

the event ID would be 123456789
so copy that ID then go to the following page,

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

and replace any text in the text box next to the submit button with the Event ID,

You should then be able to see the event's details there

Comment: I wish that were (still?) the case.  Now all that returns is a  "GraphMethodException" JSON error  "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

Comment: hmm, getting an events info via the explorer tool still seems to work for live public events, for me. i'm not sure if it still works for cancelled events. i guess it might depend on permissions and whether it was a private event or not. if thats the case, the call might require authentication i suppose.

Try and get an authentication token. If its an event you created, click the "Get Token" button which is next to the "authentication token" text box, then click "get user access token" then tick the "user_events" box, then click the "Get Access Token" button, that might allow your call to work